# ... in a read file is seen wrongly

Tags: python, file

I am reading a certain file in python into a variable:

```
with open('Folder\\File.txt') as fileToRead:
    a=fileToRead.read()
```

However, the file contains the characters `...` (three dots). These are being read as `â€¦` for whatever reason. Why is this happening, how can I prevent this, and are there any other symbols that I need to take care of when reading a file?

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your python script?

Comment: Can you verify if it's an ellipse character and not three dots?

Comment: @Jarad Issue fixed, but it was an ellipse actually

Comment: This is a problem typical for Python 2. Python 2 will not be maintained beyond 2019. So, if you start a new project try to use a recent version of Python 3.

Comment: @KlausD. but I am using `Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try :**

```
# if the file in the same directory 
file = "Filename.extension"
#else
file = "FullDestination/Filename.extension"
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    print(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

`fileToRead.read().decode('utf-8')`